# Unable to build app using electron-builder. Error: gyp failed with exit code: 1

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, electron-builder, node-gyp

I am working on the Electron app and to build executables, I'm using [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/cli)

I've the following environment:

- Electron-Builder Version: ^23.6.0,
- Node Version: v14.21.1
- Electron Version: ^10.1.5
- Electron Type (current, beta, nightly): Current
- Target: Windows

I've installed Python 3.11, node-gyp v8.4.0 (Latest 9.3 was giving error of `gyp: name 'openssl_fips' is not defined while evaluating condition 'openssl_fips != ""' in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp` so rolled backed the version), Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 and MS VS Build tools 2022 installed.
Also added python to the environment variable and VS to the npm config.

I'm getting below error:

```
> zinniax-chathub@2.7.0 build-installer D:\CodeMaster\ZinniaX-Chat-Frontend
> electron-builder

  • electron-builder  version=23.6.0 os=10.0.22621
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • writing effective config  file=zinniax-chathub-setup\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=bufferutil@4.0.7, utf-8-validate@5.0.10 platform=win32 arch=x64
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=10.4.7 appOutDir=zinniax-chathub-setup\win-unpacked
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=bufferutil@4.0.7, utf-8-validate@5.0.10 platform=win32 arch=ia32
  ⨯ cannot execute  cause=exit status 1
                    out=
> bufferutil@4.0.7 install D:\CodeMaster\ZinniaX-Chat-Frontend\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp-build


                    errorOut=gyp ERR! find VS 
    gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
    gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2017
    gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
    gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.4.33103.184) found at:
    gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
    gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
    gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v143
    gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK
    gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.4.33103.184) found at:
    gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools"
    gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
    gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v143
    gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK
    gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
    gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
    gyp ERR! find VS - not found
    gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
    gyp ERR! find VS 
    gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
    gyp ERR! find VS 
    gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
    gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
    gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
    gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
    gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
    gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
    gyp ERR! find VS 
    gyp ERR! configure error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
    gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\faiza\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.21.1\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
    gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\faiza\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.21.1\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
    gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\faiza\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.21.1\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
    gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\faiza\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.21.1\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
    gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\faiza\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.21.1\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
    gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\faiza\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.21.1\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
    gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\faiza\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.21.1\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:390:5)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\faiza\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v14.21.1\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd D:\CodeMaster\ZinniaX-Chat-Frontend\node_modules\bufferutil
    gyp ERR! node -v v14.21.1
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! bufferutil@4.0.7 install: `node-gyp-build`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@4.0.7 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\faiza\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-11T06_57_00_232Z-debug.log

                    command='C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe' 'C:\Users\faiza\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.21.1\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js' rebuild bufferutil@4.0.7 utf-8-validate@5.0.10
                    workingDir=
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! zinniax-chathub@2.7.0 build-installer: `electron-builder`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the zinniax-chathub@2.7.0 build-installer script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\faiza\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-11T06_57_00_312Z-debug.log
```

I tried various solutions:

- Deleted node-module and re-install
- Reinstall node-gpy globally
- npm update and npm install
- Installed Visual Studio build tools
- Tried with Python 2.7, 3.x, and win store python version
- VS Build tools 2022, VS Community 2022

But nothing works for me. This issue occurred after I formatted my laptop. Earlier it was working fine

Comment: Hi, would suggest taking a look at this https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9532 @faizan-saiyed

Comment: My both version are same at `C:\Users\faiza\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.21.1\node_modules\node-gyp` and `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\node-gyp` but it is still not working. Getting new error `errorOut=gyp: name 'openssl_fips' is not defined while evaluating condition 'openssl_fips != ""' in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp`

Comment: Does updating the electron version help? I think it is ages old.

Comment: you can try by passing ```"--openssl_fips=''"``` into the script you want to use, like ```npm install --openssl_fips=''```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I run `electron-builder` command and it is not taking any arguments.

Comment: I see. In that case lets update the electron version as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating the Electron to v21.2.3(latest) worked!

Answer (score 2):

u need to install python 2.7.x then add to ur PATH environment.
remove node_modules and package-lock.json
then run npm install again.

Comment: Did that, not working.